# VSTI plugin to combine different plugins

Tags: vst, cubase

I use Cubase and Miroslav Philharmonik. I want to play a melody with many different instruments as single instrument in cubase. Copy pasting the same melody to different instruments is an overkill, innefficient and makes changes really hard.

I used Reason 10 years before. I remember a plugin in Reason which combines different instruments like this. How can I do the same thing in Cubase?

Thank you.

Comment: Almost all DAWs has such feature. In FL Studio it is called layer channel. The whole concept of layering is play one note on virtual instrument that triggers multiple other instruments at one. You can also set the areas of the keyboard in order to limit one of such instruments to only one octave for example.

Comment: OK Thank you. I will search for layer chanelling in Cubase. If I can find a proper answer I will write it here. I think this question would be very beneficial for many musicians.

Answer (score 1):

In most instrument VST's like Kontakt, you can choose the input/output of the VST.
If you just open multiple instruments and route them to the same midi channel, every change you'll do in this midi channel will then affect all VST's

Answer (score 1):

Create a MIDI track instead of an instrument track to hold the MIDI notes. Create multiple instrument tracks for all the instruments. Use the “Sends” section on the MIDI track to send the one set of MIDI data to multiple instruments. One advantage of this method is you retain independent mixing of the different instruments.

Another way to deal with this is to make *shared copies* of the MIDI region in Cubase. With a shared copy, when you change one of the copies, it updates all the others. One advantage of this method is all the instruments could play the same melody at one point using a shared copy, and then they could all play something different at another time using different MIDI regions.